# Delayed Job custom job types with Whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, delayed-job, whenever

I have been using clockwork to run custom delayed jobs after every 6 minutes. I am planning on trying whenever gem instead of clockwork. Does any one have an idea how should I go about doing this with whenever gem:

```
 Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedRake.new("contact:new"),priority:1,run_at: Time.now)
```

With clockwork I was doing it like this

```
every(1.hour, 'Fetching New Contacts',at: '**:01') { Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedRake.new("contact:new"),priority:1,run_at: Time.now) }
```

With clockwork gem it was working perfect. We are moving our application to EC2 from Heroku and I do not want to use clockwork on our Amazon EC2 instance.

Any help in resolving this would be highly apprecaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should be done :

```
every 1.hour, at: 1 do
 runner 'Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedRake.new("contact:new"),priority:1,run_at: Time.now)'
end
```

Works like a charm. Here is the link to github issue:  [Custom Jobs of delayed_job with Whenever.](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/346)